# Getting an IBM WebSpehre Environment Variable Value

Tags: java, environment-variables, websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to fetch a WebSphere environment variable value called:

```
USER_INSTALL_ROOT
```

I need to set a property in java:

```
System.getProperties().put("java.security.auth.login.config", "C:\\IBM\\WebSphere\\AppServer\\profiles\\AppSrv01\\properties\\wsjaas_client.conf");
```

But I since this is way too hard coded for my WebSphere install, i was thinking to make it a little bit more flexible.

The USER_INSTALL_ROOT contains the value C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01, i was thinking of appending the rest in a string and setting the property value. I googled a bit here and there, but could not find a proper solution. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014531751

Comment: Is this administrative code, (running under an administrator context)?

Comment: @Daniel: That  one did show up in my Google search. But can't figure out which jar the AdminService class comes from.

Comment: @Scott: No I don't intend to do it that way.

Comment: Found the following note. Usually WebSphere class structure doesn't change much so I hope you can find that class in one of jars listed in this link (exchange with your WAS version). https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014286445